# Chip Card sample data

Tags: iso8583

I have successfully send ARQC to host, In response I have field 55 (ISO 8583) with different tagged data, I want to just clarify it by comparing it to sample field 55 response data. Can any one provide me sample response data of field 55 ?

Comment: I have doubt people will be willing to share these. You should expect that in the authorization response from the issuer you may have tag 91, tag 8A (it may, however, be also passed through field 39) and multiple tags 71 and 72. Individual systems may wrap these in some constructed objects or add proprietary data that is not ICC related.

Comment: I have received this in field 55 "24 91 0A DF CD 6F 69 A3 8C 79 07 30 30". Is it right or not ?

Comment: Looks almost OK to me. 24 might be just the length (decimal number of characters that follow, but that's just a guess), but the rest is just TLV encoded tag 91.

Answer (score 0):

In ISO8583 standard DE55 is allocated for EMV related data in request and response. In the response you can receive **[ARPC][ARC]** or **[ARPC][CSU]**. At times you can see template **71** or **72** which are issuer scripts with tag **9F18** optionally to identify the issuer script. Refer the payment scheme documentation for exact implementation details.